# SQL Server connection issue from DMZ machine -

Tags: sql-server, connection, dmz

We are getting the following error from a DMZ machine which has access to the DB server, however we are getting the following error -

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

A google search hasn't helped thus far.

Comment: `which has access to the DB server` translate to network protocol here. Same subnet? Ports open on firewall? What is making the connection? A user from an IDE? An application? We have no information at all other than the error.

Comment: Google returned 2600 results using your exact error message. This can be caused by quite a few things. There is next to no chance anybody from here can fix this for you with no details other than an error message.

Comment: hi all, thanks for helping thus far. This appears to be have a port translation issue. incoming port was for instance 2000 this was to be translated to 1900, and then processed at the sql server. The issue was on the checkpoint device not being able to translate more than one port to a single ip. I have since added another virtual IP address and its now working